# Is it safe to use VPNbook or similar sites?

Tags: vpn

Sometimes I need to use Internet from cybercafes or restaurants.
I'm concerned about the security when accessing critical sites such as my bank, Paypal or just my Facebook.

Besides the typical security measures (such as antivirus) I'm considering to use a VPN connection to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks and honeypots.

Among all the free VPN services I've decided to try VPNbook.

Is it safe to use VPNbook or similar sites?
Or they can sell my data or even hack my bank account?
Only paid services are safe?. or not even them?

Do you have any other advise to avoid this problems?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPN is for "privacy", they are never secure, and never will be.

You cannot control what the VPN provider does with the data that passes through it.
This week I read about [a case](http://torrentfreak.com/proxy-sh-vpn-provider-monitored-traffic-to-catch-hacker-130930/) where a VPN claiming to never log IP addresses or private information, was sniffing one of it's own servers to stalk some hacker.

I have also read about an experimental "infected" VPN server, that all it did was alter Javascript files before they were returned to the user, adding some dangerous code in that was later executed by the user's browser, and cached inside his computer. They were able to fetch ALL the user's passwords, history, and whereabouts. If I'm not mistaken, it was shown at a Hacker Conference.

So basically, anything you can see, the VPN you are using can see it too, and you should never fully trust anything with your private data.

Comment: This is not good news. Are there any trusted providers list?

Comment: You shouldn't trust them, but http://torrentfreak.com/which-vpn-providers-really-take-anonymity-seriously-111007/